# I have <div> boxes with same class with buttons. On button click a textbox should be added to the respective box

Tags: javascript, html, dom

[On pressing the second 'Add Task' button, a textbox should be added to the second div, similary with 3rd, 4th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP1dL.png) How do I refer to particular div element? What I have done below adds textboxes to the first div no matter which button is pressed.

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="project">
      LIST IT
    </div>
    <div id="board">
      Java Project
    </div>
  <template id="listTemp">
    <form class="frm" >
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter list name">
    </form>
    <button type="button" name="task" class="lst btn btn-secondary" onclick="addTask()">Add Task</button>
  </template>
    <button type="button" name="list" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="addList()">Add List</button>
  </body>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function addTask(){
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.placeholder="Enter task here";
  input.type="text";
  var br = document.createElement('br');
  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('frm')[0];
  // parent.insertBefore(input,document.getElementsByClassName('lst')[0]);
  parent.appendChild(input);

}
function addList(){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('listTemp').innerHTML;
  div.className = 'ListBox';
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
}
```

Comment: you are using )[0] so it will always return the first element in the selection

Comment: I did that check how the program was running. How do you add a textbox to the current div element?

Comment: What do you mean by current div element?. If you mean div id="projects" then you need to do document.getElementbyId('projects').appendChild(div)

Comment: I've attached a screenshot, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To refer div#project you can use document.querySelector('#project');

Comment: I'm referring to the addTask() in javascript. A new input box is always added to the same 'ListBox' div. I want it to be added to respective div box. The screenshot should clear the doubt